# How to detect if window.close() fail to execute?

Tags: javascript

In my script I need to execute `window.close();`, but it has a chance of failing **(Note: See below for explain)**, so I want to follow up the `window.close();` 
 with a `window.history.back()`, which will redirect user back a page and back to the correct web flow.

I have tried the following:

*Code 1*

```
window.close();
window.history.back();
```

The above worked all the time, however if I do this:

*Code 2*

```
window.close();
alert("123");
window.history.back();
```

The **alert go before window can even close**. So let me wonder if Code 1 is a safe code to use.

So I have the following question:

- Is it safe to assume that in Code 1, `window.close()` will always run before `window.history.back()`?

  - and only in the case that `window.close()` is not permitted, only then `window.history.back()` will get called?
- If not, then is it possible to detect the event of `window.close()` **not being called**? So I can proceed from that and execute the code I want

Note:

- The code is being run on multiple platform, and I find that in iOS10 SFSafariViewController, it does not know `window.close()` due to some reason, hence I need to call `window.history.back()` after knowing that `window.close()` failed

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found something [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/detect-browser-or-tab-closing) which explains it in detail, but essentially the answer is **you can't**. The best you can do is detect the `unload` events using `onunload` and `onbeforeunload`. Try using these, and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but `onunload` and `onbeforeunload` is not what I need, I might try it out but I doubt it works as I intended

Comment: When a window is closed, it will unload, correct? This is my theory. It worked for me, too.

Answer (score 0):

Did you considered adding a try.. catch block?

```
try {
window.close();
}
catch(error) {
console.error(error);
// Note - error messages will vary depending on browser
}
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Chrome (March 2022).  If you try the linked sample code and put in `window.close()`, the catch is never run!